# sum of (5+ (1/n^2)*sin(nx))

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone help me, please? I can't figure out how to calculate the sum of the series written above. It has to be meant as the sum of the function series, not as the sum of its Fourier series. Thank you
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

Well, the sum from 0 to infinity doesn't converge, as you can split the formula in 5 and sin(nx)/n^2, and the first term goes to infinity, while the second term is bounded from -1 to +1.